# Checking if the current user liked an URL using the built-in like action (og.likes)

Tags: javascript, facebook

My application implements a custom like button using Facebooks offical [built-in like action](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/).

The only missing piece is to disable the button if the user has already liked the resource. After testing various approaches using FQL which were all unsuccessful, I've just tried to issue a get request against https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>/og.likes which lo and behold returns the Open Graph likes of the current user.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a way to filter the result for a specific object_id. Can anyone recommend a solution or knows a way to accomplish the same using FQL? Be advised that we are talking Open Graph Likes here which seem to differ from the standard likes created using the Facebook Like button.

Comment: This is seemingly a bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407658155957868

Answer (score 3):

I've also been struggling to know how to get information about these og.likes using the graph API or FQL.  They don't seem to be stored in any of the usual tables (url_like, or link_stat).  This may not be the "right" way to do it but here's how I do it.

In order to check if the user has liked the object, I am hitting the Graph API as you mention, with the URL graph.facebook.com/[userid]/og.likes.  Then I just loop through the array in the response, and look for one that matches the URL or ID of the object that I'm interested in.  It's not particularly efficient if the user has a lot of og.likes, but it gets the job done.

Comment: The bigger issue here I believe is that a query on an individual user's og.likes would allow disabling the button, but does not allow for displaying the number of likes on an object. That's necessary to match up with the standard facebook like functionality.

Comment: Agreed, that is what steered us away from using og.likes -- there is no way to ask Facebook how many there have been for a particular object.  The poster didn't seem to be interested in that, or perhaps hadn't yet realized that it was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether API is available or not.

But, you have workaround. As you know the resource that is being viewed, you know the user id, when ever action gets posted, store that in your db and use that info to disable like.

I will keep you updated, once I find more info.

**EDIT**

> An FQL table containing the Open Graph URLs that a user has Liked.
>
> To read the url_like table you need
>
> user_likes permissions for all Open Graph URLs liked by the current
>   session user friend_likes permissions for all Open Graph URLs like by
>   friends of the current session user

source: [user likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/)

Comment: Yeah sure I could do that I'd like to avoid storing that kind of data in my database at all costs.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Unfortunately I've been there and contrary to the docs this table seems to contain only "real" likes, no open graph likes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can set a Like button for your URL then check if a user liked it by ANDing "url=" in the WHERE clause:
`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() and url="http://www.yourUrl.com"&access_token=...`

Note that the url has to be in "quotes"